# Qt Qml and tensorflow build using Bazel

Tags: qt, tensorflow, qml, bazel

Currently I am working on a project that includes Qt Qml and tensorflow. I got the method to build Qt widget application but I could not find out how to build Qt Qml using Bazel.. Pls help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Which platform are you targetting?

I worked in a project integrating Tensorflow with Qt/QML for Linux, iOS and android. One option is to compile Tensorflow with make for each platforms. Details about how to do this with an example app are given in this post.

https://mechatronicsblog.com/machine-learning-on-desktop-ios-and-android-with-tensorflow-qt-and-v-play/